# How to compare tow column of data and create a new data frame to store it?

Tags: python

My dataFrame looks like this.

```
A = [Buy,Hold,Sell,Buy,Hold,Sell]

B = [Buy,Hold,Sell,Hold,Hold,Buy]
```

How to compare 2 column and create a new column C showing column A = column B

C should be like `C= [Buy, Hold, Sell,None, None, None]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a try :

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] == df['B'], df['A'], None)
```